# Compressing a JSON response from a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, apache2, gzip

We have an app that queries for locations for a customer.  We're getting to the point where some customers could have upwards of 10,000 locations.  The JSON response for this can get quite large, over 1mb sometimes.

I'm wondering first off the best way to compress this.  We have apache in front of a Rails app running in trinidad with JRuby.  Can I just set mod_deflate to always compress any responses that are application/json?  How might I go about doing this?

Next, what is the browser support for gzip'd json?  When I gzip a sample response of 200k it goes down to 30k.  That's a significant savings.  We're really like to be able to minimize the size of that response without having to minimize the number of locations returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the browser supports gzip'd/deflated data, then JSON will go through it just fine. AJAX data is just a regular HTTP request that was done on behalf of a script, rather than a human. At the HTTP level, there's absolutely zero difference between transferring some HTML or a JSON string - it's just data.

Answer (score 11):

In general, for newer versions of Rails, you can do it by adding

```
use Rack::Deflater
```

before the "run" line in the **config.ru** file. This will work perfectly with browsers/clients that support gzip. We use it in production on major websites.

**Note** for JRuby users: This assumes that your Rails app is launched through Rack, which it often isn't for JRuby. You need a recent version of JRuby-Rack and configure it in Warbler to run in 'rack' mode instead of 'rails' mode.

Answer (score 1):

For Googlers... [I'm running Apache 2.2.16 and don't care about IE6]

JSON Responses with Content-Encoding = gzip didn't happen until I edit mod_deflate.conf to include this:

```
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
```

You can check server response headers with Firefox / Firebug / Net tab

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have apache's mod_deflate installed by running this command.

```
a2enmod deflate
```

If this command installed it, restart apache. If not, you're good for now.

```
service apache2 restart
```

In `apache2.conf` usually located at `/etc/apache2` append this line to the end of the file. This will include a file that we'll create in a little.

```
Include mod_deflate.conf
```

Next, we'll edit the mod_deflate.conf with our options:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
    \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ \
    no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary

#Skip browsers with known problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

The first block of code disables gzipping exes, gzs, pdfs.. etc

The second block of code skips deflation from browsers that don't support it.

Finally, restart apache again

```
service apache2 restart
```

The settings were copied from the link below:
http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2_mod_deflate